# symfony image upload resize

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using symfony to develop a website and have it mostly functioning, but I need it to resize images to a certain size when they are uploaded. I installed the sfImageTransfomPlugin to allow me to resize them, and figured out that I need to overload the save() method in the model class, but I can't find any documentation to get the information about the uploaded image so that I can resize it. Has anyone done this before or can point me to some documentation for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resizing images in model is not a good practice, imho.

The plugin's [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfImageTransformPlugin) already tells about simple implementation:

```
public function executeUpload($sfWebRequest) {
    [...]
    $img = new sfImage($filename, 'image/jpg');
    $img->resize(100, 100);
    $img->save();
    [...]
}
```

Assuming you bind submitted values via `bind` method:

```
$this->form->bind(...);
```

Name of uploaded file you can get from your form object:

```
$file = $this->form->getValue('file');
$filename = $file->getOriginalName().$file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
```

Comment: right, I've already got that much figured out. How do I get `$filename` for a new image upload?

Comment: you were really close, but I had to use `$file->getSavedName()` to get the filename in order to able to change it. But otherwise it worked. Much thanks!